# Running Prolog commands from a bash script

Tags: bash, prolog

To start the Prolog shell that loads my program I can simply enter `swipl app.pl` into my terminal. Then, to invoke the predicate (function) `verify(InputFile)` defined in `app.pl` (the Prolog program) with a text file argument, I write `verify('path/to/file.txt')`. Is it possible to write a bash script that performs all of the above tasks?

It seems possible to run built-in Prolog commands from a bash script, such as the "write line" command, by entering the following `swipl << writeln('Hello')` into the bash script. However, if I attempt to do the same for the `verify` predicate defined by me I end up with the following error.

**Input**

```
Input: swipl app.pl <<< "verify('tests/unit/af-test1.txt')."
```

**Output**

```
true
ERROR: Type error: `character_code' expected, found `-1' (an integer)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] char_code(_2720,-1)
ERROR:   [10] '$in_reply'(-1,'?h') at /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/8.0.3_1/libexec/lib/swipl/boot/init.pl:848
```

For context, the `verify/1` predicate is defined by the below code.

```
verify(Input) :-
   see(Input), read(Transitions), read(Labling), 
   read(State), read(Formula), seen,
   check(Transitions, Labling, State, [], Formula).
```

Comment: Maybe your problem is into the verify predicate... Can you post the code?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `<<<`, you can use the `-g` option in this way:
`swipl -s file -g "goal,halt."`. `halt` is needed, otherwhise SWI will not terminate.

Moreover, you can write a bash script like this:

```
VARIABLE=1                                                                                                            
swipl -s test -g "test($VARIABLE),halt."
```

and the predicate, in this case `test/1`, will be called with `1`, like `test(1)`.

Comment: Preferably use `swipl -s test -g "test($VARIABLE)" -t halt` to get a non-zero exit code if the goal fails or throws an error.

Comment: This works quite well, but is there anyway to print `true` to the console whenever the `test` predicate returns `true`. Currently, nothing is printed to the console unless `test` returns `false`?